# Readline all spellings of the word in large and small letters

Tags: node.js

I created code with readline but it works only with 1 word (Hello). And me need its works with all spellings of the word in large and small letters (Hello, HEllo, hello, heLLo, HELlo and more)
Trying to search in google but cant find answer
Please help me!

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Type command here:', function(command) {
    if (command === 'Hello') {
        console.log('Hi!');
    } else {
        console.log('Goodbye');
    }
    rl.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reach your goal is to convert your `command` to [lowercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
To do so you have to change

```js
if (command === 'Hello')
```

to this

```js
if (command.toLowerCase() === 'hello')
```

Notice that your `'hello'` also should be lowercased.

UPD.
Here is an example

```js
const commands = ['hello', 'Hello', 'HEllo', 'some other text', 'heLlo', 'helLO'];

for (const command of commands) {
  if (command.toLowerCase() === 'hello') {
    console.log('Hi!');
  } else {
    console.log('Goodbye');
  }
}
```

UPD2.
The main approach is to compare two lowercased strings so you have to apply `toLowerCase()` on both `GetMessage` and `Command` before comparison.

```js
const message = "hello, it's me, Mario!";
const command = "Hello";

const lowercasedMessage = message.toLowerCase();
const lowercasedCommand = command.toLowerCase();
if(lowercasedMessage.startsWith(lowercasedCommand)){
    console.log("Hi!");
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes i know this. But i dont need only lower and large. I need its were together like this HeLLO, heLLo, hEllo, hELLO and more

Comment: @onlyinOHIO My approach can handle every possible combination of upper- and lower-cased letters, just try it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for good examples. I rewrite code and now i need convert var Command = "Hello" to this but your code sent only true or false. Can help please?

Comment: `var Command = 'Hello'`
`var ConvertedCommand = '' //???`
`if (!GetMessage.startsWith(ConvertedCommand)) return`

Comment: @onlyinOHIO the main approach is to compare two lowercased strings so you have to apply `toLowerCase()` on both `GetMessage` and `Command` before comparison.

Comment: @onlyinOHIO updated my answer with example